# How to set the creation date on Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a file created a while ago that I want to upload on Google Drive, while preserving it's original creation date.

How to do that with the Google Drive SDK?

Answer (score 1):

The API reference says that the createdDate JSON property is not writable. But in at least the JAVA library, you have a method setCreatedDate() that can be use to set this property to your convenience.

However, I've just tried to do that with the API explorer, and the API returned me a 400 error - Bad request. So i think this is not possible

Jérôme